# Android FragmentTransaction commit() - Activity has been destroyed

Tags: android, android-activity, fragmenttransaction

when restarting the app I had problem with `getActivity()` returning `null`, so I solved it with `onAttach()`. However now I have a new problem with `FragmentTransaction` `commit()` and `commitAllowingStateLoss`. It says Activity has been destroyed.

```
    Activity mActivity;
    private FragmentActivity myContext;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        myContext =(FragmentActivity) activity;
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    private void navigateToFragment(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentTransaction transaction = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

The navigation works the first time i run the app, but when reopening the app it crashes at transaction.commitAllowStateLoss();

```
(mActivity).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                enableMenu();
                openMenu();
                navigateToFragment(new BlankFragment());
            }
        });
```

Pls help, don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

check whether `activity` is finishing or not before transacting a fragment(in this case)
Below is the snippet:-

```
if (!isFinishing()) {
  FragmentTransaction transaction = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Comment: I've tried it, and isFinishing() is true the second time I open the app. What do I have to do to make it !isFinishing() again ?

Comment: And why isn't the app resetting 100% when closing the app with back button ? When running the app after closing it, onCreate is not called in MainActivity... To reset the app 100% I have to kill it by closeing the prosess(button left to homebutton).

Answer (score 0):

When clicking "Back" and exiting the app, some prosesses will be stored in the memory for faster startup. So to make the app reset a 100% I had to add this in MainActivity.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

If anyone has a better solution please post it!